# Trying to find the lowest value for multiple lists within one list

Tags: list, python-2.7

The BlocksPerColumn is only part of the whole, but it's just for the idea.

```
BlocksPerColumn = [[[336350.0, 7089650.0, -7.0, 0.1665, 1.5, 1, 1, 'Ghost', 3, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 2, 'Ghost', 0, -30000.0], [336350.0, 7089650.0, -5.0, 0.1542, 1.5, 1, 2, 'Ghost', 3, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 2, 'Ghost', 0, -30000.0], [336350.0, 7089650.0, -3.0, 0.2259, 1.5, 1, 3, 'Ghost', 3, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 2, 'Ghost', 1, 153475.49999999997], [336350.0, 7089650.0, -1.0, 0.2753, 1.5, 1, 4, 'Ghost', 3, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 2, 'Ghost', 1, 200158.49999999997], [336350.0, 7089650.0, 1.0, 0.2236, 1.5, 1, 5, 'Ghost', 3, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 2, 'Ghost', 1, 151301.99999999997]], [[336450.0, 7089550.0, -7.0, 0.1791, 1.5, 2, 6, 3, 6, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 1, 7, 5, 'Ghost', 0, -30000.0], [336450.0, 7089550.0, -5.0, 0.1707, 1.5, 2, 7, 3, 6, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 1, 7, 5, 'Ghost', 0, -30000.0], [336450.0, 7089550.0, -3.0, 0.2248, 1.5, 2, 8, 3, 6, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 1, 7, 5, 'Ghost', 1, 152436.0], [336450.0, 7089550.0, -1.0, 0.2791, 1.5, 2, 9, 3, 6, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 1, 7, 5, 'Ghost', 1, 203749.5], [336450.0, 7089550.0, 1.0, 0.3098, 1.5, 2, 10, 3, 6, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 1, 7, 5, 'Ghost', 1, 232760.99999999994]], [[336450.0, 7089650.0, -5.0, 0.1488, 1.5, 3, 11, 'Ghost', 7, 2, 1, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 6, 'Ghost', 0, -30000.0], [336450.0, 7089650.0, -3.0, 0.1961, 1.5, 3, 12, 'Ghost', 7, 2, 1, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 6, 'Ghost', 0, -30000.0], [336450.0, 7089650.0, -1.0, 0.2499, 1.5, 3, 13, 'Ghost', 7, 2, 1, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 6, 'Ghost', 1, 176155.5], [336450.0, 7089650.0, 1.0, 0.2939, 1.5, 3, 14, 'Ghost', 7, 2, 1, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 6, 'Ghost', 1, 217735.5]], [[336550.0, 7089350.0, -7.0, 0.1774, 1.5, 4, 15, 5, 10, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 11, 9, 'Ghost', 0, -30000.0], [336550.0, 7089350.0, -5.0, 0.2551, 1.5, 4, 16, 5, 10, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 11, 9, 'Ghost', 1, 181069.5], [336550.0, 7089350.0, -3.0, 0.3489, 1.5, 4, 17, 5, 10, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 11, 9, 'Ghost', 1, 269710.49999999994], [336550.0, 7089350.0, -1.0, 0.3707, 1.5, 4, 18, 5, 10, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 11, 9, 'Ghost', 1, 290311.5], [336550.0, 7089350.0, 1.0, 0.3037, 1.5, 4, 19, 5, 10, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 11, 9, 'Ghost', 1, 226996.5]], [[336550.0, 7089450.0, -5.0, 0.1719, 1.5, 5, 20, 6, 11, 4, 'Ghost', 2, 12, 10, 'Ghost', 0, -30000.0], [336550.0, 7089450.0, -3.0, 0.3121, 1.5, 5, 21, 6, 11, 4, 'Ghost', 2, 12, 10, 'Ghost', 1, 234934.5], [336550.0, 7089450.0, -1.0, 0.3491, 1.5, 5, 22, 6, 11, 4, 'Ghost', 2, 12, 10, 'Ghost', 1, 269899.49999999994], [336550.0, 7089450.0, 1.0, 0.326, 1.5, 5, 23, 6, 11, 4, 'Ghost', 2, 12, 10, 'Ghost', 1, 248070.0]], [[336550.0, 7089550.0, -7.0, 0.1494, 1.5, 6, 24, 7, 12, 5, 2, 3, 13, 11, 'Ghost', 0, -30000.0], [336550.0, 7089550.0, -5.0, 0.1598, 1.5, 6, 25, 7, 12, 5, 2, 3, 13, 11, 'Ghost', 0, -30000.0], [336550.0, 7089550.0, -3.0, 0.2061, 1.5, 6, 26, 7, 12, 5, 2, 3, 13, 11, 'Ghost', 1, 134764.5], [336550.0, 7089550.0, -1.0, 0.2554, 1.5, 6, 27, 7, 12, 5, 2, 3, 13, 11, 'Ghost', 1, 181353.0], [336550.0, 7089550.0, 1.0, 0.3218, 1.5, 6, 28, 7, 12, 5, 2, 3, 13, 11, 'Ghost', 1, 244101.0]], [[336550.0, 7089650.0, -5.0, 0.1334, 1.5, 7, 29, 'Ghost', 13, 6, 3, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 12, 2, 0, -30000.0], [336550.0, 7089650.0, -3.0, 0.1711, 1.5, 7, 30, 'Ghost', 13, 6, 3, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 12, 2, 0, -30000.0], [336550.0, 7089650.0, -1.0, 0.193, 1.5, 7, 31, 'Ghost', 13, 6, 3, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 12, 2, 0, -30000.0], [336550.0, 7089650.0, 1.0, 0.2498, 1.5, 7, 32, 'Ghost', 13, 6, 3, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 12, 2, 1, 176061.0]]]

Deepest_Block_All_Columns = [] # Will have the lowest Z-value for each column.
        for item in range(0,len(BlocksPerColumn)):
            Deepest_Block_Column = [100] # Making sure that the z value at start is always lower.
            for i in range(0,len(BlocksPerColumn[item])):
                if BlocksPerColumn[item][i][2] < Deepest_Block_Column:
                    Deepest_Block_Column = BlocksPerColumn[item][i][2]
            Deepest_Block_All_Columns += [Deepest_Block_Column]
            Deepest_Block_Column = [100]
        print Deepest_Block_All_Columns
```

As a result I am receiving:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Why am I not getting -7.0 (since -7.0 is the lowest), and why am I receiving 0's:

```
[[-7.0],[ -7.0]........]
```

I would like one lowest value of index 2 (which is a z-coordinate) for each item.

Comment: let me rephase this:  You are trying to find the lowest value in a lis of lists? Are all cells valid to check against?  Im not sure if you are just going to check every cell of this structure and compare it to find the lowest number within the sets, or what?

Comment: Yes to the first Q. As blocks PerColumn shows (there are approxiamtely 7 lists like: [336350.0, 7089650.0, -7.0, 0.1665, 1.5, 1, 1, 'Ghost', 3, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 2, 'Ghost', 0, -30000.0] per list of which many lists exist. 
In [336350.0, 7089650.0, -7.0, 0.1665, 1.5, 1, 1, 'Ghost', 3, 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 'Ghost', 2, 'Ghost', 0, -30000.0] the second index (third positions) is a z-coordinate as you can see here its -7. I'm trying to find one lowest z values for all lists within the list that contains approximately 7 lists and add them to Deepest_Block_All_Columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you will not get a list of lists as a result. Because whenever you **add** two lists the result will be a merged list.
For having a list of lists you should do `Deepest_Block_All_Columns.append([Deepest_Block_Column])`
Also, Your code snippet is correct. When I run it gives me
`[-7.0, -7.0, -5.0, -7.0, -5.0, -7.0, -5.0]`
Try to append lists as shown above, may be that helps.

**NOTE:** This does not actually answers your question
As I can see you are taking a list to compare as Deepest_Block_Column then take it as a simple variable because you have already taken `Deepest_Block_All_Columns` as a list, when you `append()` that variable then it will be added to that list
So may be making that change might help. Do tell me whether those changes help or not

Comment: Thank you so much. The appending solved the problem:
Deepest_Block_All_Columns.append([Deepest_Block_Column])